# Different behaviour of Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: reactjs

I use component `react-dropzone` that doesn't work on server if I don't do `require('react-dropzone').default;`

The problem, that locally on mac it works only if I do import `require('react-dropzone');` without `default`. So it cant work in both places with same require statement.

Why can this happen ? Is it possible to make it work on both server and locally without changing everytime `.default` everytime depending on runtime ?

Comment: Sounds like you might be transpiling the package in one situation and not in the other?

Comment: what is transpiling ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source-to-source_compiler ... E.g. babel is a transpiler that converts ES2015+ to ES5.